# Converting string value to Boolean for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to easily convert values in my dataframe to Booleans. Each column can contain values like "YES", "NO" or "NaN".

Converted the values with numpy to an ndarray in a list comprehension but if I convert it to a dataframe I get the error

```
ValueError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 159 columns
```

However, if I print the the length of my ndarray it outputs 5

```
import numpy as np
death_columns = ['Death1', 'Death2', 'Death3', 'Death4', 'Death5']
death_counts = combined_dataframe[death_columns]
death_data = [np.where(death_counts[c] == "YES", True, False) for c in death_columns]
len(death_data)
```

This is how I thought to create a dataframe again.

```
death_counts = pd.DataFrame(death_data, columns = death_columns)
```

Comment: `combined_dataframe[death_columns].apply(lambda c: c.map({'Yes': True, 'No': False})` or `combined_dataframe[death_columns].replace({'Yes': True, 'No': False})`

Comment: Thanks, that should work. But can you also explain why I can't convert an ndarray like this to a dataframe? The output checks out and I don't understand why the error mentions 159 columns.

Comment: can you update your question with a fully reproducible **minimal** example (just a few columns)?

Comment: Also, isn't that your answer going to ignore the NaN values?